# .NET Standard and a runtime requirement

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I want to build a class library which I want to use in number of applications; some applications are on `.NET Core 3.0` and some on full `.NET Framework 4.7.2`. Since there are variety of applications, I am about to build a class library project on `.NET standard 2.0`.

Will there be any problem to run full `.NET Framework 4.7.2` application with my new netstandard library on the computers where .NET Core runtime is *not* installed and where only .NET Framework 4.7.2 runtime is installed? Is there any such dependency on the .NET Core runtime (or any other runtime for that matter) for .NET standard libraries to work in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 applications?

(I have some .NET Framework 4.6.1 applications too but they will soon be migrated to .NET Framework 4.7.2.)

As I understood it, there should not be any problem but has anyone experienced any practically issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.7.2 supports .NET Standard 2.0, so, yes, having a reference from the full framework project to the .NET Standard library works. See [.NET implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) for details.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the .net standard 2.0 class library reference in the .net Framework 4.7.2 application and the .net core 3.0 application. I have checked on my side, they all work well. You can try it on your application.